# Redux search ".get() is not a function"

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

in "videos.json" i have :

```
[
  { "id":"1", "name":"hotfuzz cover", "category":"music", "rating":"100" },
  { "id":"2", "name":"photos by me", "category":"photos", "rating":"78" },  
  { "id":"4", "name":"my backstreetboys cover", "category":"music","rating":"13"},
  { "id":"5", "name":"my crazy salsa skills", "category":"dance", "rating":"90" },
  { "id":"6", "name":"stand up show", "category":"comedy", "rating":"42" }
]
```

=======================================================================

in core.js

```
export function setVideos(state, videos) {

  const list = List(videos);  
  return state.set('videos', list)

}
```

**1.question : i want to set "name" in state, like i set videos. is there a short way to do this with immutablejs? I couldn't reach id, name, category, rating without mapping**

=========================================================================

```
export function isPartialMatch(text, textItem) {
    return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(textItem.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}


export function searchItems(state, textItem) {

  const videos= state.get('videos');

  const newName = videos.filter(item => isPartialMatch(item.get('name'), textItem));

  return state.set('videos', newVideos);
}
```

=========================================================================
in Filters.jsx
 inside react render function i have;

```
<div>    
        <input
          type="text"
          className="searchBar"
          placeholder="Search by name..."
          style={({
            marginBottom: '0.5em'
          })}
          onChange={event => this.props.searchItems(event.target.value) }
        />
  </div>
```

=========================================================================

**2.question: i am trying to search in names (textItem is text input). But i get "item.get is not a function" error. how can i able to search in names?** Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you show code for your 2nd question?

Comment: i added codes in react side..

Comment: instead of `const list = List(videos); ` , pls use `const list = fromJS(videos)`;

Comment: altough i dont understand why, fromJS(videos) works just fine! thank you!